# Imbalanced Dataset for Multi Label Classification

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

So I trained a deep neural network on a multi label dataset I created (about 20000 samples). I switched softmax for sigmoid and try to minimize (using Adam optimizer) :

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_pred)
```

And I end up with this king of prediction (pretty "constant") :

```
Prediction for Im1 : [ 0.59275776  0.08751075  0.37567005  0.1636796   0.42361438  0.08701646 0.38991812  0.54468459  0.34593087  0.82790571]

Prediction for Im2 : [ 0.52609032  0.07885984  0.45780018  0.04995904  0.32828355  0.07349177 0.35400775  0.36479294  0.30002621  0.84438241]

Prediction for Im3 : [ 0.58714485  0.03258472  0.3349618   0.03199361  0.54665488  0.02271551 0.43719986  0.54638696  0.20344526  0.88144571]
```

At first, I thought I just neeeded to find a threshold value for each class.

But I noticed that, for instance, among my 20000 samples, the 1st class appears about 10800 so a 0.54 ratio and it the value around which my prediction is every time. So I think I need to find a way to tackle tuis "imbalanced datset" issue.

I thought about reducing my dataset (Undersampling) to have about the same number of occurence for each class but only 26 samples correspond to one of my classes... That would make me loose a lot of samples...

I read about oversampling or about penalizing even more the classes that are rare but did not really understood how it works.

Can someone share some explainations about these methods please ?

In practice, on Tensorflow, are there functions that help doing that ?

Any other suggestions ?

Thank you :)

PS: [Neural Network for Imbalanced Multi-Class Multi-Label Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152660/neural-network-for-imbalanced-multi-class-multi-label-classification) This post raises the same problem but had no answer !

Comment: why not using all samples you have and use that imbalance data to use an anomaly detection algorithm instead ?

Comment: If I understand well, what you suggest is to train my network on my (9) classes (that are "well" represented in my dataset) and then train another network on my "poorly represented" class (like doing Binary Classification on this class) ?

Comment: No. I suggest using algorithms made to detect very small minority, differents for the huge majority of your data. They are often called anomaly detection algorithm because usually when you try to detect anomaly you have a lot of "good" sample but very few "abnormal" ones. However these algorithms are often made to classify between two classes. So maybe it's not good to you but may be it can be a part of more complex classifying process

Comment: OK thank you for the idea (and your extra explaination) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, having 10000 samples in one class and just 26 in a rare class will be indeed a problem.

However, what you experience, to me, seems more like "outputs don't even see the inputs" and thus the net just learns your output distribution.

To debug this I would create a reduced set (just for this debugging purpose) with say 26 samples per class and then try to heavily overfit. If you get correct predictions my thought is wrong. But if the net cannot even detect those undersampled overfit samples then indeed it's an architecture/implementation problem and not due to the schewed distribution (which you will then need to fix. But it'll be not as bad as your current results).

Comment: I thought it might be a problem from my network at first but it works just fine for single label classification such as MNIST (when I had Softmax). But still I am going to try to overfit with 26 samples per class ! Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Ok so definitly you were right .. unfortunately for me ! But, as I said before, the exact same architecture used to learn and perform really well on MNIST dataset and on a dataset I created (multi class single label) !
The only thing that changed is that I replaced Softmax by Sigmoid ..

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not the class imbalance, rather just the *lack of data*. 26 samples are considered to be a very small dataset for practically any real machine learning task. A class imbalance could be easily handled by ensuring that each minibatch will have at least one sample from every class (this leads to situations when some samples will be used much more frequently than another, but who cares).

However, in the case of presence only 26 samples this approach (and any other) will quickly lead to overfitting. This problem could be partly solved with some form of data augmentation, but there still too few samples to construct something reasonable.

So, my suggestion will be to collect more data.

Comment: 26 is not the size of my dataset just the number of occurence of one of my class throught the whole dataset (which is 20000 samples). Thank you for the idea of "ensuring that each minibatch will have at least one sample from every class". It is the same idea as Oersampling right ? :)

Comment: No oversampling is increasing the number of instances in the minority class via sampling.