# How to balance data in a multi class text classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-classification

I have a multi class text classification problem with 29 output classes. This is the distribution of records across the 29 classes in training dataset.

I want to know how should I go about balancing my data using upsampling? For upsampling, should I upsample all classes to 1337 rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imbalanced Dataset for Multi Label Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285537/imbalanced-dataset-for-multi-label-classification)

Comment: I would try to use SMOTE, whereby I would create 100 artificial samples for each class. See how that works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to up-sample the data size. You can use weighted loss function to balance the incentive of the model to correctly classify all classes (the same affect).

For example, the loss of the class with smallest amount of samples ("CONVEYOR SAFETY") will be `L*1337/45` and the loss of the class with highest amount of samples will be `L*1337/1337=L`.

Answer (score 2):

Upsampling (or oversampling) may produce a more balanced dataset, but it also encourages *overfitting* due to the duplication of minority class examples ([Kotsiantis et al.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/95df/dc02010b9c390878729f459893c2a5c0898f.pdf)).

As mentioned by [user2974951](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2974951/user2974951), SMOTE is a method which produces samples based on the existing data, reducing the aforementioned risk of overfitting minority classes ([Chawla et al.](https://jair.org/index.php/jair/article/view/10302/24590) show marked improvement using SMOTE in comparison to bias tuning).

Alternatively, you can try choosing a learning algorithm which is less susceptible to an imbalance-based bias (e.g. SVM works well with imbalanced data [Sun et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167923609001754)).

If this is not possible, *term-based weighting* as proposed by [Liu et al.](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-1-84628-754-1_10) or similar weighting methods as mentioned by [Mark.F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9673730/mark-f) can help improve prediction accuracy when training with the imbalanced dataset.

Good luck!