# How to deal with Imbalanced Dataset for Multi Label Classification

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I was wondering how to penalize less represented classes more then other classes when dealing with a really imbalanced dataset (10 classes over about 20000 samples but here is th number of occurence for each class : [10868  26  4797    26  8320    26  5278    9412    4485    16172 ]).

I read about the Tensorflow function : weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits) but I am not sure I can use it for a multi label problem.

I found a post that sum up perfectly the problem I have ([Neural Network for Imbalanced Multi-Class Multi-Label Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152660/neural-network-for-imbalanced-multi-class-multi-label-classification?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and that propose an idea but it had no answers and I thought the idea might be good :)

Thank you for your ideas and answers !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is my suggestion you can modify your cost function to use in a multi-label way. There is [code](https://github.com/AliAbbasi/Multilabel-Image-Classification-with-Softmax/blob/master/multilabel-softmax.py) which show how to use Softmax Cross Entropy in Tensorflow for multilabel image task.

With that code, you can multiple weights in each row of loss calculation. Here is the example code in case you have multi-label task: (i.e, each image can have two labels)

```
logits_split  = tf.split( axis=1, num_or_size_splits=2, value= logits  ) 
labels_split  = tf.split( axis=1, num_or_size_splits=2, value= labels  )
weights_split = tf.split( axis=1, num_or_size_splits=2, value= weights )
total         = 0.0

for i in range ( len(logits_split) ):  
    temp   = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( logits=logits_split[i] , labels=labels_split[i] )) 
    total += temp * tf.reshape(weights_split[i],[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if I understand correctly, you use Softmax so what you do is dividing your multi label problem in two multi class single label problem (one for shape and one for object category). That's not my case, I have a "real" multi label problem (not separable), so I guess what you propose doesn't fit my problem. But thank you for your answer that might be usefull for later for me :)

Comment: so maybe in your case `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` can be useful. Good luck.

Comment: yes that's what I am currently doing ! But don't really figured out how to tackle my imbalanced dataset with this yet :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` for multiclass classification.

For example, for 4 classes, where the ratios to the class with the largest number of members are `[0.8, 0.5, 0.6, 1]`, You would just give it a weight vector in the following way:

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        targets=ground_truth_input, logits=logits, 
        pos_weight = tf.constant([0.8,0.5,0.6,1]))
```

Comment: I don't think that `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` accepts multiclass problems.

Taken from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits):
"This is like sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits() except that pos_weight, allows one to trade off recall and precision by up- or down-weighting the cost of a positive error relative to a negative error."

Comment: Are you sure that your logits are multi-class then, though, and not just logits for individual classes (multiple labels)? 

As I see it, multi-class problems contain several classes which are not independent (so we use softmax), while multi-label problems can contain multiple classes which are independent, which prompts the sigmoid for each separate class. At least, that's how I see the TF source code.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not entirely sure that I understand your problem given what you have written. The post you link to writes about multi-label AND multi-class, but that doesn't really make sense given what is written there either. So I will approach this as a multi-class problem where for each sample, you have a single label.

In order to penalize the classes, I implemented a weight Tensor based on the labels in the current batch. For a 3-class problem, you could eg. define the weights as the inverse frequency of the classes, such that if the proportions are [0.1, 0.7, 0.2] for class 1, 2 and 3, respectively, the weights will be [10, 1.43, 5]. Defining a weight tensor based on the current batch is then

```
weight_per_class = tf.constant([10, 1.43, 5]) # shape (, num_classes)
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=3) # shape (batch_size, num_classes)
weights = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.multiply(onehot_labels, weight_per_class), axis=1) # shape (batch_size, num_classes)
reduction = tf.losses.Reduction.MEAN # this ensures that we get a weighted mean
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
        onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits, weights=weights, reduction=reduction)
```

Using softmax ensures that the classification problem is not 3 independent classifications.